# Comparing two object are indentical in kotlin

Tags: android, object, kotlin

I have a two kotlin object which are very identical data without any change, but getting return false. which has to be return true if two object are identical, only if change then it should be return false.

Doing checking objects are:

```
private var emp1: Employee? = null
var emp2: Employee? = null

fun dataChanged(): Boolean {
    return if (emp1 != null && emp2 != null) {
            emp1 != emp2
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
```

I checked the data in log, which is not changing anyhing not even space.

Employee defiend as  follows,

```
data class Employee(
 //...
 ): Parcelable {
 //...
 }
```

No equals and hashcode.

here using for changing data change on edittext ->  **TextInputEditText**, **TextWatcher**. Any suggestion, where, i'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `Employee` defined?

Comment: You're example is still not complete for me to reproduce it. Are all the properties `Employee` also implementing `equals` (either through overriding or via `data class`)?

Comment: perhaps it is irrelevant, just remind that your dataChanged() method will always return `false` if one object is null. No matter if the other changed or not.

Comment: can you print 2 object to Logcat and share the Log here

Comment: Employee's properties are relevant. Showing just that class is data class is not enough.

Comment: log data added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a `data` class [compiler automatically derives](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) the following members from all properties declared in the [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors):

- equals()/hashCode() pair;
- ...

Therefore `equals` method execution depends on parameters of **primary constructor**.

If you use some other objects in primary constructor make sure they are also `data` classes or have **overriden** `equals` method.

I suggest to put logs before comparison of two objects and check whether they contain equal data.

EDIT:

> I have a two kotlin object which are very identical data without any change, but getting return false.

Your function `dataChanged()` returns `false` for two identical objects because of condition `emp1 != emp2`. The name of the function says that it will return `true` if objects are not identical, `false` - if they are identical, i.e. data not changed. So the function `dataChanged()` works as expected.

Comment: log data added.

Comment: It would check it on my side if you added whole definition of `Employee` class.

Comment: Also I see another object `Money` and enums, please add definitions of them too.

Comment: Please check my edited answer, maybe you have an error of understanding the purpose of `dataChanged` function.